# How to make Windows Indexing pause when the computer is in use?

Tags: windows-7, windows, search-indexing

I think some years ago Windows indexing service on my computer paused when the computer was in use. The Indexing Options window showed something like "Indexing paused" (or maybe "slowed down") "because the computer is in use" when I moved the mouse.

Now it does not pause. The Indexing Options windows does not change when I move other windows or do something else on the computer. It always shows "Indexing NN files..." or so. I am on the same installation of Windows 7 32-but.

The question is **not** about how to manually pause or disable the indexing service. The question is how to make it automatically pause or slow down when the computer is in use and automatically resume when the computer is idle.

Comment: Is Indexing complete?  It does not change if complete. Indexing just a few new items is very quick, so indexing would be normally complete in a stable system. Try Rebuilding the Index (needs to run overnight or a least a few hours) and then run Excel or something and see if it pauses.

Comment: @Alexander Gelbukh can you check the service uses up any processing time?

Comment: @John No, for some reason it decided to rebuild the index; it is now half-way.

Comment: So start an app and see if indexing pauses

Comment: @Albin SearchIndexer.exe does not consume much CPU (1% or so). My problem is not CPU but the disc: recently the system because awfully slow, and I suspect this might be because the indexer constantly uses the disk (and maybe prevents the system from reading the DLLs it needs). My real question is why my PC because so slow, but this is not a good question to ask at SE.

Comment: @John Oops, it has just changed to "Complete" (and not changing when I open Excel, which is normal). But it was actively indexing for much time (days probably) and it did not stop when I opened other apps. So the question is what should I / others do in this situation next time.

Comment: Indexing is relatively speedy so you need to catch it in the act. I have a Windows 7 machine here but I haven't used Windows 7 in production for about 5 years. Windows 10 occasionally (not often) tells me it has paused and Windows 7 when I used it did the same (occasionally, not often)

Comment: @Alexander Gelbukh the rease to check the CPU wasn't to see how much it "takes" but to confirm that it is actually active. So you did that, is that correct? It might be interessting to use [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) or even better Resource Monitor to see how much load indexing actually puts on the HD. Maybe it only looks like indexing is the problem.

Comment: Here in Windows 1909, there is "Indexing complete" on the main dialog and the "Pause" button is not disabled. Click the Pause button, nothing happens but for the Pause button to become disabled. This kind of behaviour means the SearchIndexer code hasn't been maintained for a while. However, testing may reveal that the CPU % activity of the indexing process may depend on the machine's power plan.

Answer (score 2):

Stupidly, for years now, whenever I need to get some work done at any computer running Windows, and I don't want to listen to my computer's fan going like crazy, I right-click on the "SearchIndexer.exe" process and select "Suspend". Et voilà, the annoying fans slow down considerably, and I can hear myself think again. Isn't Windows great? :-|